# Which function to use when linking multiple tables with Eloquent (Laravel)?

Tags: php, laravel, database, eloquent

I'm working with the latest version of Laravel and trying to create a website for my tabletop games club. The part where I'm totally lost is the relationships with Eloquent and how I should setup everything.

Here's my database :

```
+-----------+  +--------+
| game      |  | editor |
+-----------+  +--------+
| id        |  | id     |
| name      |  | name   |
| editor_id |  +--------+
+-----------+

+-----------+  +------+
| game_type |  | type |
+-----------+  +------+
| game_id   |  | id   |
| type_id   |  | name |
+-----------+  +------+
```

If I understood the documentation correctly, I should create a `BelongsTo` function in the **game model** and then create a `HasMany` function in the **editor model** because a **game** has `1` **editor** and an **editor** has `n` **games**.

Here's my **game** model :

```
class Game extends Model{

    use HasFactory;

    const TABLE_NAME = 'Game';
    protected $table = self::TABLE_NAME;

    public function editor():BelongsTo{
        return $this->belongsTo(Editor::class);
    }

    public function types():BelongsToMany{
        return $this->belongsToMany(Type::class);
    }
}
```

And here's my **editor** model :

```
class Editor extends Model{

    use HasFactory;

    const TABLE_NAME = 'Editor';
    protected $table = self::TABLE_NAME;

    public function games():HasMany{
        return $this->hasMany(Game::class);
    }
}
```

But what about all the types of games now? A **game** has `1-n` **type** and a **type** has `0-n` **games**. For this, I created the pivot (?) table in the middle and added foreign keys, and created the function `types():BelongsToMany` in the **game** model.

Then I created the **type** model with the `games():BelongsToMany` function in it:

```
class Type extends Model{

    use HasFactory;

    const TABLE_NAME = 'Type';
    protected $table = self::TABLE_NAME;

    public function games():BelongsToMany{
        return $this->belongsToMany(Game::class);
    }
}
```

After all this, I tried to use those functions in my code to retrieve all kinds of data from the database and to understand how it works, but nothing does.

I headed right over the internet to look up for an answer but I didn't understand anything. And since my English level is not the best, Laravel documentation is sometimes difficult to understand.

So my questions are :

1. What are the correct functions to use?
2. How do they work? << *The part I struggle the most with*

I don't do a lot of posts because the internet is full of information and examples, but I'm getting to a point where I need a clear and precise answer to my problem.

If there is any missing information, I will gladly point it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relationships are the following.

- A Game belongs to an Editor.
- An Editor has many Games.
- A Game has many GameTypes through the pivot table game_type.
- A GameType belongs
  to a Game and belongs to a Type.
- A Type has many GameTypes and has
  many Games through the pivot table game_type

**Game model**

```
class Game extends Model
{
    public function editor()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Editor::class, 'editor_id');
    }

    public function gameTypes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(GameType::class, 'game_id');
    }

    public function types()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Type::class, 'game_type', 'game_id', 'type_id');
    }
}
```

**Editor model**

```
class Editor extends Model
{
    public function games()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Game::class, 'editor_id');
    }
}
```

**Type model**

```
class Type extends Model
{
    public function gameTypes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(GameType::class, 'type_id');
    }

    public function games()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Game::class, 'game_type', 'type_id', 'game_id');
    }
}
```

**GameType Model**

```
class GameType extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'game_type'; // Name of your pivot table
}
```

Make sure your table and column names follow Laravel's naming conventions to avoid any issues. Once you have established these relationships, you can retrieve associated data from Eloquent's query methods.

```
// Retrieve a game and its editor
$game = Game::find(1);
$editor = $game->editor;

// Retrieve all games of an editor
$editor = Editor::find(1);
$games = $editor->games;

// Retrieve all game types of a game
$game = Game::find(1);
$gameTypes = $game->gameTypes;

// Retrieve all games of a game type
$gameType = GameType::find(1);
$games = $gameType->games;
```

Comment: With your example, I understand that I have to see the relationships separately so a game has an editor and an editor can have several games. So now I understand the "simple" relationships.

However, I don't understand how the part with the intermediate tables works. There is the hasManyThrough function but I don't understand its mechanic and how I put the pivot table in the middle.

Is your example sufficient for my use case ?

Comment: Create a pivot table in your database schema to represent the many-to-many relationship between games and types. The pivot table should have the foreign keys game_id and type_id to establish the relationship.

Comment: I already have created the table but I'm not sur to understand your updated example. Is the `GameType` class the model for the pivot table or is it the model for the `Type` table ?

Comment: In the updated example, the GameType class should represent the model for the pivot table, not the Type table. The GameType model will be used to define the relationship between the Game and Type models through the pivot table.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. I'll give it a try in a few minutes and I'll come back for a feedback. I think I understood how it works now.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I think that explain more than it should be. More information they can find in the Documentation and in the College.

Comment: Hello ! So it works well and I understood how to use those functions. I even created more tables and more models. Thank you very much for your help.